# Grails dbCreate='validate' fails to recognize existing table

Tags: sql-server, grails, datasource, grails-orm

I have the dataSource configured as follows:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "validate"
        url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myservername"
    }
}
```

My SQL Server "myservername" has a database "products" with a table "inventory" owned by "dbo". Here is my Inventory class mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    table 'products.dbo.inventory'
    version false
    columns {
        id column: 'itemKey'
        itemId column: 'itemId'
        inactive column: 'inactive'
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, I get this error:

*nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: products.dbo.inventory*

**Also, when I change dbCreate from "validate" to "update" or any other ones, it works fine.**

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance,
Skudder

Edit to respond to question -

I merged the changes to my object and I still get the error. Here is my object:

```
class Inventory {

Integer id
String itemId
String description
Boolean inactive

static mapping = {
    table 'products.dbo.inventory'
    version false
    columns {
        id column: 'itemKey'
        itemId column: 'itemId'
        description column: 'description'
        inactive column: 'inactive'
    }
}

static constraints = {
    itemId (maxSize: 30)
    description (maxSize: 100)
}

static hasMany = [productInventoryDefaults: ProductInventoryDefaults, productTreeNodes: ProductTreeNodes]

String toString() {
    return this.itemId
}

}
```

and table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inventory](
[itemKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[itemId] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[inactive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Inventory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[itemKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Does Grails actually not change anything in that table, maybe a field type? What are the domain object and table structure?

Comment: Are you saying that if in "update" mode, Grails tries to change something (even though it fails because it does not have DDL permissions on the db), then it will not recognize the table's existence in "validate" mode? Because there are some differences in column types between the object and database table.

Comment: @VictorSergienko, I've included my object and table in my original post.

Comment: Exactly. Not as if it TRIES to change it, but `"validate"` means that Hibernate will verify that the tabe exactly matches Hibernate's "idea" about the table :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe here Hibernate has no means to see how to generate primary keys.

I'd try to either:

- alter `id` field to `IDENTITY`;
- or/and tweak [`id` field mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) to use Java-side `generator`;
- or, even simpler, try connecting to a test database with `dbCreate = "create"` and proper  permissions, see what table structure will Hibernate create, and alter your table to that one.

If you need to retain the table structure intact, then only the second way is the way.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! I'll try and let you know what I come up with.